# How to make people properly tag their questions at least with programming language or toolkit?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, questions, ignored-tags

Some people, mostly newbies, often tag questions in such a way that ignored tags practically cannot work, e.g.: `nsstring` `substring`.  (In this particular case I could probably add `ns*` to ignored list, but there are "worse" cases).  I could in principle go to such questions and retag them, but in many cases I don't even know what a proper language/toolkit tag would be.

Can anyone suggest a way to "force" better tags on questions or at least autohint question writers about what tags would be useful?

Comment: Red hot irons. Or hungry squirrels inserted into  their pants. Alternatively, not allow them to create new tags, as I have suggested ad nauseam.

Comment: Can't you not create new tags till you have 250 rep or something?

Comment: @Josh: Yep, but this doesn't help much (for this) because the question is how to require at least one "globally descriptive" tag rather than how to avoid new tags.

Answer (score 2):

Besides implementing a higher rep (currently 250) for creating new tags, how about a small AJAX div that opens up under the tag saying

> The following tags will be created: {tags}. Some similar existing tags are: {existing_tags}.

This will give them a visual notice that they are creating new tags and to maybe use one of the existing tags instead.

Comment: @Josh: Maybe not "similar" but "related".  E.g. `java` is not similar to `hashmap`, but it can be related if the latter was about `java.util.HashMap`.

Comment: We need a higher rep for tag creation. Definitely should be like 1k or so

Comment: There are so many tags you shouldn't **ever** need to create new ones. Really.